# last_online attribute of user remains `nil`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a small real-time chat and I'm stuck with listing the users online. I have a custom `User` model, and in way to list the list online users out I made a migration `add_last_online_to_users last_online:datetime`. Then, in my `user.rb`:

**EDITED**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages, dependent: :delete_all
    class << self
        def from_omniauth(auth)
            provider = auth.provider
            uid = auth.uid
            info = auth.info.symbolize_keys!
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
            user.name = info.name
            user.avatar_url = info.image
            user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
            user.save!
            user
        end
        def online_now
            where("last_online > ?", 15.minutes.ago)
        end
    end
end
```

in `application_controller.rb`:

```
def show_online
    @users = User.online_now
end
```

in `sessions_controller.rb` **EDITED**:

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    cookies[:user_id] = user.id
    user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)
end
```

in `messages_controller.rb` **EDITED**:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        if current_user
            @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
            @message.save
            current_user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)
            format.html{redirect_to root_path}
            format.js
        else
            format.html{redirect_to root_path}
            format.js {render nothing: true}
        end
    end
end
```

and finally the view:

```
<ul>
    <%= @users.each do |user| %>
        <li><%= user.name %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**
But when I check after signing in or sending a message in console - there's no users listed in the view, and when I try to call `User.online_now` on console, it returns `undefined method 'online_now' for User`

**ANOTHER EDIT**
I removed `self` from `online_now` method in `User` class as I've been told, and now there's no `undefined method` error, but still no users online in my view :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not saving last_online attribute in sessions_controller.rb, just assigning the value. Instead try this:

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    cookies[:user_id] = user.id
    user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)
end
```

Same thing in messages_controller.rb. Try replacing `current_user.last_online = Time.now` with `current_user.update_attributes(last_online: Time.now)`

Comment: that helped, thank you! but it still doesn't show users online in the view :(

Comment: I guess that last_online is now stored into database. Does `User.online_now` returns users in a rails console?

Comment: sorry for the late response! I checked via console, it returns `undefined method 'online_now' for User`. In my question I provided the whole `User` model

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already making the methods of User static with the 'class << self', it could be causing trouble that you are defining the method as self redundantly. Try without the 'self' on the declaration of online_now.

Comment: Thank you! now in the console I found `User` who's `online_now`, but still there's no users online in the view :(((